Call async function in class constructor in NodeJS
is it okay to call async function in class constructor? I'm not expecting any returned values when calling it, i just want to call that async function to connect to kafka connection.
I called the connect async method to constructor,  I just want to connect it. see code below.
Code is something like this:
const httpStatus = require('http-status');
const { Kafka, Partitioners } = require('kafkajs');

const logger = require('../logger');

const { KAFKA_ACKS } = require('../constants/kafka-constants');
const { KafkaInstanceError } = require('../../utils/custom-errors/class-errors');
const { KAFKA_INSTANCE_ERRORS } = require('../constants/error-messages');
const { HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE } = require('../../utils/response-codes');

class Producer {
  #config;

  #key;

  #producerInstance;

  static #instances = {};

  constructor(key, kafkaConfig = {}) {
    this.#config = kafkaConfig;
    this.#key = key;

    this.#connect();
  }

  async #connect() {
    if (Producer.#instances[this.#key]) return;
    if (!Producer.#instances[this.#key]) Producer.#instances[this.#key] = this.#key;

    this.#producerInstance = await this.#initProducer();
    await this.#producerInstance.connect();
  }

  #initProducer() {
    const kafka = new Kafka(this.#config.kafka);
    const producer = kafka.producer({
      ...this.#config?.producer,
      createPartitioner: Partitioners.DefaultPartitioner,
    });
    return producer;
  }

  async produceEvent(events = {}) {
    try {
      if (Object.keys(events).length === 0) {
        throw new KafkaInstanceError(
          KAFKA_INSTANCE_ERRORS.EVENT_OBJECT_EMPTY,
          HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE.DATA_PROCESSING_ERROR,
          httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        );
      }

      logger.info('sending events to kafka notification');

      await this.#producerInstance.send({
        topic: this.#config.topic,
        acks: this.#config?.producerSendOptions?.acks || KAFKA_ACKS.ALL,
        messages: [events],
      });

      logger.info('event sent to kafka notification');
      return events;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(error.message);
      throw new KafkaInstanceError(
        error.message,
        error.code || HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        error.statusCode || httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      );
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Producer,
};


You shouldn't, because that's not what constructors are for. A constructor has one job: to ensure that a new object is is a valid state, which should not involve any IO or side-effects - but it can depend upon the results of some IO, but you accomplish that by using a factory function - which does the IO first, and only afterwards then invokes the ctor.
